# Create number of fields based from choices

Tags: django, django-models

*I'm trying to figure out how to populate fields in my model based on previous field selection.

For example, if **FIELD_CHOICES = 3**

Create 3x TextField()

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('published','Published'),
                        ('draft','Draft '))
    FIELD_CHOICES = (('1','1 Title and body field'),
                    ('2','2 Title and body fields'),
                    ('3','3 Title and body fields'),
                    ('4', '4 Title and body fields'),
                    ('5', '5 Title and body fields'))

    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='blog_post')


    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub_title = models.TextField(max_length=50,default="")
    title_and_body_fields = models.IntegerField(choices=FIELD_CHOICES,
                                                default=1)

    **/// create number of title and body Textfields based on what was 
    /// selected in title_and_body_fields**


    created = models.DateField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='created')

    status = models.CharField(max_length=250,
                    choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                    default='draft')

    object = models.Manager()
    postManager = PostManager()


    class Meta():
        ordering = ('publish',)

    def __strd__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('my_blog:post_detail',
                        args=[self.publish.year,
                                self.publish.month,
                                self.publish.day,
                                self.slug])
```

In the end i decided to do the following.

I added 5 seperate TextFields for Title and Body and added blank=True

```
title_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    title_5_body = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: You don't, the number of columns is "static" in a relational database. What you usually do is create a model (like `TitleBody`, and make a many-to-one relation with `Post`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible.

I think you misunderstand how Models work. Have a look at the Django docs for models [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/).

Basically the way Django saves your models, is through an ORM ([Object-Relational-Mapping)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

This means that the model you write, with the fields contained within it, are transformed into a database query, generating a table.

In the docs for models, you can see this piece of code:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

is transformed to this [SQL](https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-database-sql.html) query:

```
CREATE TABLE myapp_person (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

This means that Django, under the hood, creates database tables for each Model you have in your app.

---

**So how does work in Django?**

Well, these SQL statements are generated when you run `python manage.py makemigrations`. The actual tables are created when you run `python manage.py migrate`.

This means that you only run these commands once (For every change to your model), and there will be only one table created for your model.

---

**So why can't I add extra TextFields to an object?**

This is because for each model there is only one table in the database, and your model would be stored like this:

```
id   |   first_name   |  last_name 
----------------------------------
1    |   John         |  Doe
2    |   Jane         |  Doe
...  |   ...          |  ...
```

If you were to add an extra field (for instance `phone_number`) to John Doe, you'd need to add that field to the entire table.

So in your case, your choice is between no extra body and title fields, or a set amount extra fields for *each object.*

---

**Ok, what now?**

Well, there are a few ways to do this. Your best bet would be to create a ManyToMany relationship to a Model called something like `PostBody`, which would allow you to create an arbitrary amount of bodies for a set post.

You could modify the save method of you `Post` model to automatically create a set amount of `PostBody` objects for that object.

You can read read more about ManyToManyField [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: If there can *never* be more than five title and body fields, it may be easier and simpler to define five of each  in the model, compared to having a separate database table of `PostBody` objects with a `ForeignKey` relationship to a Person. All but the first need to permit blank values. The storage cost of blank  fields is small. The drawback is database querying may get complex...

However, in the general case where the maximum number of such title/body objects is undefined or large, using separate objects and ForeignKey is definitely the way to go.

Comment: ... if you need to search for something that may be in field 1, or field 2, ... or field 5. (Couldn't quite splice this into my earlier comment)

Comment: This is also a valid option. My answer's purpose was more to outline that you cannot dynamically declare fields for a DB object.